# remove SKSpriteNode after 5 seconds

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

How can i remove my `SKSpriteNode` after 5 seconds in my function like this. I have tried with a `NSTimer` called a func delete my `BonusSprite`
but after 5 sec my application crash  :

```
let timerApparitionBonus = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(13, target: self, selector: Selector("ApparitionBonus"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    func ApparitionBonus() {

        var BonusApparitionX = UInt32(self.frame.size.width)
        var BonusApparitionY = UInt32(self.frame.size.height)

        BonusApparitionX = arc4random() % BonusApparitionX
        BonusApparitionY = arc4random() % BonusApparitionY
        BonusSprite.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(BonusApparitionX),CGFloat(BonusApparitionY))
        BonusSprite.setScale(0.8)
        self.addChild(BonusSprite)
    }
```

EDIT :

This is my code from `DidMoveToView` to function who delete my sprite.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    //BackGround

    self.scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.addChild(SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "MyParticle")!)
    self.scene?.size = CGSize(width: 640, height: 1136)

    //Placement du Vaisseau :

    Vaisseau.setScale(2)
    Vaisseau.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2)
    Vaisseau.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Vaisseau.size)
    Vaisseau.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Vaisseau.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Vaisseau
    Vaisseau.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Meteorites
    Vaisseau.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Bonus
    Vaisseau.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    self.addChild(Vaisseau)

    //Timer créer enemis

    CreationEnemisTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("CreationMeteorites"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    //Score

    timerScore = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.7, target: self, selector: Selector("ScoreUpper"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    ScoreLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width / 3, height: 20))
    ScoreLabel.center = CGPoint(x : self.frame.size.width / 2,y : self.frame.size.height / 4)
    ScoreLabel.text = "Score : \(Score)"
    ScoreLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1, alpha: 0.3)
    ScoreLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view?.addSubview(ScoreLabel)

    //Aparition des Bonus (timer)

    let myFunction = SKAction.runBlock({self.ApparitionBonus()})
    let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(5)
    let remove = SKAction.runBlock({self.removeBonus()})

    self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([myFunction, wait, remove]))
}
```

```
func ApparitionBonus() {

    var BonusApparitionX = UInt32(self.frame.size.width)
    var BonusApparitionY = UInt32(self.frame.size.height)

    BonusApparitionX = arc4random() % BonusApparitionX
    BonusApparitionY = arc4random() % BonusApparitionY

    BonusSprite.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(BonusApparitionX),CGFloat(BonusApparitionY))
    BonusSprite.setScale(0.8)

    BonusSprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Bonus
    BonusSprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Vaisseau
}
```

```
func removeBonus() {

    BonusSprite.removeFromParent()
}
```

Answer (score 7):

try this

EDIT: realized it wouldn't remove the sprite, this will work.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
      let myFunction = SKAction.runBlock({()in self.ApparitionBonus()})
      let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(5)
      let remove = SKAction.runBlock({() in self.removeSprite()})
      self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([myFunction, wait, remove]))
    }
    func ApparitionBonus() {
       self.addChild(bonusSprite)
    }
    func removeSprite() {
       bonusSprite.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use `SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(sec: NSTimeInterval)` instead of `SKAction.removeFromParent()` if you want it to fade out rather than disappear suddenly.  It automatically calls `removeFromParent()` after it has animated the `alpha`.

Comment: I think you forget () after self.ApparitionBonus and self.removeSprite ? Because i have some errors in my compilation

Comment: And when i try your code i have a error when my Bonus spawn like this :2015-10-22 20:40:19.801 SpaceSurvival[1828:85702] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'Bonus.png' (100 x 100)] position:{243, 606} scale:{0.80, 0.80} size:{80, 80} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: @MathisDelaunay inside of the code you posted, say if bonusSprite.parent == nil { self.addChild(bonusSprite) }

Comment: @DanielMihaila There is always the problem :/

Comment: you're getting this error because you're trying to add your sprite more than once. Where are you calling the function? update?

Comment: i call the func in the didMoveToView in a Selector in timer.

Comment: why don't you delete your NSTimer attempt and post the code I provided you with in didMoveToView(), or anywhere where it'll only be called once. Remember that removeSprite() function has to be outside of didMoveToView

Comment: Don't worry my function is outside of didMoveToView. I give you my code from didMoveToView

Comment: @MathisDelaunay I'm going to edit your answer to what I think you should try

Comment: I tried with your edit but i can't run my application

Comment: I just tested it and worked for me, I changed my answer to exactly what I did, don't know how else to help you

Answer (score 0):

// If we create a SKSpriteNode by a function look like that!

```
func gooseWarnningLabelShow () {
    var spriteNodelabel        = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "labelBack2")
    spriteNodelabel.position   = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: frame.size.height*0.90)
    spriteNodelabel.size       = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width*0.70, frame.size.height*0.06)
    spriteNodelabel.alpha      = 0.2
    spriteNodelabel.zPosition  = 21.0
    self.addChild(spriteNodelabel)
    spriteNodelabel.runAction(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.waitForDuration(5.0),
            SKAction.removeFromParent()
            ])
    )
}
```

Use this function to create a SKSpriteNode! In that function we have a SKAction which is execute after 5 second delay and remove the SKSpriteNode!